# Writing a matrix model in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to write the following matrix:

[image: matrix]

I define `n=100` and I generate the following code:

```
D = toeplitz([0 1 zeros(1, n-2) -1]/ (2*h));
```

but I get a wrong matrix. How can I correct it?

Comment: Use `diag`. I think one of the examples in the documentation is for this matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2917957/david) said you can use diag as following:

```
clc
clear all
close all
%------------------
n = 100;
h = 5;
% Positive Ones
A1 = ones(n-1,1);
Arr1 = diag(A1,1);
% Negative Ones
A2 = -ones(n-1,1);
Arr2 = diag(A2,-1);
% your array
Array = (1/(2*h))*(Arr1+Arr2);
```